# Set innerHTML of anchor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anchor

Here is my code

```
var test = '${URL}'
```

`${URL}` is an anchor tag containing the follow `<a href="google.com">LINK</a>`

I want to change this LINK to TEST. Is it possible to do that? I couldn't find any method to just change the innerHTML of the anchor tag.

Comment: '${URL}' is not JavaScript nor HTML. I'm not sure if this is any language related to JS, but if it is, please include that in the tags to your question. Also, try doing `test.src = 'http://google.com'` to change your target url to `http://google.com`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: looks like some template replacement code

Answer (score 4):

First give an id to the html link.
Then you can access it and update the text by using innerHTML property as below example.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="google.com" id='link'>LINK</a>

<script>
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML="Test";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 2):

The variable 'test' does not hold a DOM object. All that is to it at that point is a String that happens to look like html.

If you did this with the test variable.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML += test;

div.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML = 'test';
```

You could do it. But at that current stage in your code, the variable test is no more that a String.

If you could create a better picture of the environment and what you want to happen we could help you a lot better.